Estoy usando gspread en colan para importar una gsheet, pero me formatea todos los datos string
Buenas soy nuevo en esto. Estoy usando gspread  en colab para importar una gsheet, pero me formatea todos los datos a object y cambiar cada columna es un quilombo. Necesito automatizar la carga de estos datos que se actualizan diariamente y no es una buena opcion bajarlos en csv manualmente.
Por eso estoy intentando

from google.auth import default
auth.authenticate_user()
creds, _ = default()
gc = gspread.authorize(creds)
hoja = gc.open(nombre_archivo)
datos = hoja_de_trabajo.get_values()
df = pd.DataFrame(datos)

¿Hay alguna forma de traer el formato de cada columna?
